# Не получается сделать проверку деления на 0

Tags: python

```
    print('Noob calculator v. 1.0')
number_1 = int(input('Write first number:'))
number_2 = int(input('Write second number:'))
operation = input ('Select operation: +;-;*;/;')

if operation == '+': 
    print(number_1 + number_2)
elif operation == '-':
    print(number_1 - number_2)
elif operation ==  '*':
    print(number_1 * number_2)
elif operation == '/':
    if number_1 or number_2 != 0:
        print(number_1 / number_2)
    else:
        print('bb.nice try')
```

Answer (score 1):

Хоть я и проголосовал за закрытие, но в этом конкретном случае нет смысла проверять оба числа. Ведь это на ноль делить нельзя, а сам ноль делить можно. Поэтому нужно проверить только второе число:

```
if number_2 != 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно отлавливать исключение `ZeroDivisionError`.

***Пример:***

```py
try:
    print(number_1 / number_2)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('bb.nice try')
```